# Should DriverManagerDataSource be used in a real live application with Multi-Tenancy Enabled?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am building a REST API that is focused on separating the users' data from each other. The way I have implemented this is by using `Spring` and a multi-tenant approach. Meaning I have a `Main_DB` which keeps the information about Users and their Databases. And for each User I will have a separate DB with the app-specific data. So far so good, I implemented this by using `AbstractRoutingDataSource`, and on each call, the user sends a `JWT` token with his data, and through his data, I connect him to his DB real quick and get the data he needs.

When creating the User `DataSource` I used a plain `DataSource` Object with all the info needed. But this Object caused problems for my DB (Postgresql) because when a user made just one request, the connection to the DB stayed alive **forever**. So I switched over to `DriverManagerDataSource`. It works perfectly, whenever a user makes a call to my REST API, he gets the data needed, and the connection is closed, so the DB will not be overflown and won't throw an `Exception` later.

Is using `DriverManagerDataSource` a safe and correct way to do this?
I have read (old) answers that said, you should not use this since it uses no Connection Pool.
Should I use this? If not, what should I use?

Thank you.

Comment: No, the (old) answers are correct, use a proper connection pool.

Comment: @M.Deinum But it does exactly what I need.
It closes the connection after each call. How can I implement something like this with a connection pool?

Comment: The problem with that is that is is slow, really slow. You will never get a performant system with the `DriverManagerDataSource`. Building up a connection takes time, if that isn't an issue use it, else use something like a `SingleConnectionDataSource` to cache the connection for the duration of the users session (ander close/remove it as soon as he logs-out).

Comment: @M.Deinum first of all thank you for taking the time to check my problem. Secondly, I understand what you mean, but if I do not use the following approach after 100 users login to the app and make requests. The DB will throw an error saying that there are too many connections open.

Comment: You need to limit the number of connections per pool (you probably need just 1 or 2, the default generally is around 10). And you  need to actually close/remove the datasource when a user logs out (or a session timeout happens). YOu will have to do some cleaning and limiting connections else something will give in the end.

Comment: And what would be a good Class to use with connection pooling in my Scenario? How can I configure the number of connections per pool? And `datasource.getConnection().close()` does not work either, how am I supposed to close the connection?

Comment: You shouldn't close the connection (nor should you be working with a Connection directly). Upon logout you should close the datasource!. How to configure the number of connections depends on the pool you use (as mentioned you can use something like the `SingleConnectionDataSource` which opens just 1 connections and reuses).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234328/discussion-between-renis1235-and-m-deinum).